# Deleted environment variable still work

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

I have installed a gcc, but afterward I discovered that the version of that gcc is kinda old.( version 3.4.0)  But I have add its directory to the Path in windows' environment variable.

So, I went delete that directory in the path in environment variables in the computer setting. But it still worked after I deleted it. Whenever I tried to type **gcc -v** in the command prompt, it told me **version 3.4.0...**

I have checked both the **Path** of *user variable* and *system variable*. No sign of it , but it still work. why?

Comment: Have you checked variable value inside in shell you are running "gcc -v"?

Comment: @DmitryPoroh yes. There is no sign of that variable there. But when I type gcc -v, it sill work

Comment: This is mystic. Look for another installed gcc in paths :)

Answer (score 2):

When modifying env var(s) (as you did), from (e.g.) the *Win* native interface (*Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> System Properties (Advanced) -> Environment Variables*), it's good to know that **only the apps that start afterwards** will *see* the changes; all the already running apps, will continue running with the environment they had at their startup. So, if you changed some env var(s), you should **restart any running app** that relies on the changes. To make things sure, log off and log on again (this implies restarting all running apps), or better: reboot your machine (in case you want the env var(s) changes to propagate to running system services as well).

As for your *gcc* dilemma (simply running *gcc* still works), run `where gcc` (which is the equivalent of *Ux*'s `which`), which will output *gcc*'s full path (using the same engine that the command interpreter does when locating *gcc*). AFAIK *where* is available since *WinVista* (at least it is present in *Win7*).